# iOS safari asks to login automatically on website when not wanted

Tags: html, ios, authentication, mobile-safari

After previously logging into a website I'm building, on testing iOS safari constantly presents "**Log in to: [website name]**" then a button with my username. On inspection I was able to get rid of this by deleting the login form hidden in the html footer on every page, however I would like to keep the form in my code.

```
<form action="/" method="POST" class="login" id="login-model">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="NAME" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
    <button class="btn">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

Is there something I can change about this html so that iOS doesn't "help me out" and bring up the login automatically, this is not wanted.

This is what I currently see:

[image: Mobile iOS image of issue]

Comment: I can't recreate the issue but maybe `autocomplete='off'` in the form tag could prevent this

Comment: Add an image above to show you what I mean, its very very odd

Comment: Just bumping this to ask if there was ever a solution to this problem? I've encountered it myself

Comment: not that ive seen :(

Comment: You, as the developer, cannot choose of force to hide it. You can, however, as a visitor on the site, remove your saved logins from your keychain for that website and it will no longer prompt you to login. I know its not a fix per se but at least it will save some time in debugging and testing diff things.

Comment: great thanks, not ideal, but something that Apple needs to look i guess